# What is the greatest factor in DoS network flow connection tempo?

Tags: ddos, denial-of-service

I'm conducting some research on botnet detection. I'm specifically looking at Zeek/Bro connection logs (so network flows). I was wondering what affects the tempo of the succession of network flows seen when an infected device conducts a DoS attack and or port/IP scanning. Is it a function of the device's computational power or function of the network bandwidth or maybe some combination of the two?

I'm not a network guy. I'm looking at it more from a statistical lens.

Comment: Define "tempo".

Comment: Computational power needed for attack is minimal. What you need is bandwidth or attacks that can kill bandwidth if it's not a direct attack case.

Comment: @schroeder when analyzing Zeek connection logs DoS appears to create many connections sometimes 100's within a 10th of a second.